# I am new to PostgreSQL and I am currently in the process of writing a trigger for table. Using below code

Tags: postgresql

```
DECLARE
    immutable_cols TEXT[] := ARRAY['id','sq_id','last_date'];
    op_value JSON;
BEGIN
    IF TG_OP = 'UPDATE' THEN
        SELECT json_agg(json_build_object('Updated', pre.key , 'From', pre.value, 'To',  post.value)) INTO  op_value 
        FROM jsonb_each(to_jsonb(OLD)) AS pre CROSS JOIN jsonb_each(to_jsonb(NEW)) AS post 
        WHERE pre.key = post.key AND pre.value IS DISTINCT FROM post.value;
        RAISE NOTICE '% ', op_value;
        IF (json_array_length(op_value) > 0 )THEN
            INSERT INTO table_name (col_1,col_2) 
            values (OLD.col_1,op_value);
            NEW.col_3 = now();
        END IF;
        IF(NEW.col_4) THEN
            INSERT INTO REQUEST_TRAIL (col_1,col_2) 
            values (OLD.col_1,json_build_object('From',OLD.col_4,'To',NEW.col_4));
            NEW.col_5=now();
        END IF;
      RETURN NEW;
    END IF;
END
$$
LANGUAGE plpgsql VOLATILE;
```

I got a error for

> ERROR:  invalid input syntax for type boolean: "{"To" : "Tech"}" 
>   CONTEXT:  PL/pgSQL function line 22 at IF SQL state: 22P02

Comment: What's unclear about the error message `{"To" : "Tech"}` is not a boolean value

Comment: I am usig before update trigger, This is old data using  col_4 column.